# Fixing button styling with tailwind and rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I have a slight problem regarding styling with button_to in rails 7. I'm using tailwind and the following html produces the result in the image.

```
<div class="flex">
    <button type="button" class="flex-1 bg-indigo-600 py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
        Download
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="flex-1 ml-3 bg-white py-2 px-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
        Delete
    </button>
</div>
<div class="flex">
    <%= button_to 'Download', some_path(@obj), data: { turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "flex-1 bg-indigo-600 py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" %>
    <%= button_to 'Delete', some_path(@obj), data: { turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "flex-1 ml-3 bg-white py-2 px-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray 50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" %>
</div>
```

[image]

the upper two buttons are what I'm trying to achieve, but for some reason the button_to tags will fail to generate this. It's likely due to them generating the form elements, but I would like to know how I can fix this? Also I'm looking for solutions working with button_to's instead of link_to's.

Comment: Strange that this is a behavior, have you tried using devtools to see if anything could be overriding `flex-1`?

Comment: I think it's due to the fact that `<%= button_to %>` generates the html `<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/some-action"><button data-turbo-confirm="Are you sure?" class="flex-1 bg-indigo-600 py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" type="submit">Download</button><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="LeRG4sZ0PCbGfjztZISuuUNhogb5aUlEioz1V4IidUjHgmpOZcSyDrB-sybKxfcT5N4fEvPNtt73oIy_9KdgVg" autocomplete="off"></form>`

Comment: and I suppose that the form somehow breaks the styling.

Comment: Here is a link to reproduce the example https://play.tailwindcss.com/9byuZ9h60D

Answer (score 3):

`button_to` generates a form with a submit button. This button is not a [flex item](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Flex_Item) because it's no longer a direct child of the flex container. This causes `flex-1` to have no effect.

Use [`contents`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#contents) class on the form to "ignore" it and make the button a flex item:

```
<div class="flex space-x-3">
  <%= button_to "Download", "/path", form_class: "contents", class: "flex-1" %>
  <%= button_to "Delete",   "/path", form_class: "contents", class: "flex-1" %>
</div>
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

or add `flex-1` to form instead:

```
<div class="flex space-x-3">
  <%= button_to "Download", "/path", form_class: "flex-1", class: "w-full" %>
  <%= button_to "Delete",   "/path", form_class: "flex-1", class: "w-full" %>
</div>
```

or use `grid`:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-3">
  <%= button_to "Download", "/path", class: "w-full" %>
  <%= button_to "Delete",   "/path", class: "w-full" %>
</div>
```

or mix it all together:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-3 md:grid-flow-col auto-cols-fr">
  <button type="button"> Download </button>
  <%= button_to "Download", "/path", form_class: "contents" %>
  <%= button_to "Delete",   "/path", form_class: "flex", class: "flex-grow" %>
  <%= button_to "Delete",   "/path", class: "w-full" %>
</div>
```